# How to manipulate an IQueryable with Linq in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, iqueryable

I want to access through a Javascript PopOver event (mouse over) a list of cities in a given country by raising a window as follows

[image: View]

For this in the list of countries I have the following  code that executes the following method in the CountryController

```
<td>
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" id="@item.Id">@item.NumberCities</a>

 </td>

      <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                    title: setData,
                    html: true,
                    placement: 'right'
                });

                function setData($id)
                {
                    var set_data = '';
                    var element = $(this);
                    var id = element.attr("id");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Countries/CitiesDetailsModal/" + id,
                        method: "post",
                        async: false,
                        data: { id: id },
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            set_data = data;
                        }
                    });

                    return set_data;

                }
            });
        </script>
```

CountryController.CS:

```
 public ActionResult CitiesDetailsModal(int? id)
 {
      var paises = countryRepository.GetCountriesWithCities();

      return View();
 }
```

The problem is that my GetCountriesWithCities () method returns an IQueryable and I cannot manipulate the countries variable with Linq

The result of my countries variable is ...

[image: Debug]

As can be seen above, this method lists the countries and within them the cities that correspond

But how can I access them? How can I pass to the View the List filtered by the CountryId that I receive as a parameter in the CitiesDetailsModal () method?

My Modal view currently receives a City model and I want to show it with the following CitiesDetailsModal.CSHTML format

```
@model IEnumerable<SoftwareCore.Common.Models.City>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CityNumbers";
}

<h4>Citys</h4>

<div class="container">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {      
        <p><label>Nombre:</label> @item.Name)</p>      
    }

</div>
```

Where my models at play are:

Country.CS:

public class Country : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Country")]
[MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} only can contain {1} characters length.")]
public string Name { get; set; }

public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "# Cities")]
public int NumberCities { get { return this.Cities == null ? 0 : this.Cities.Count; } }
```

}

City.CS:

```
public class City : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "City")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "el campo {0} solo puede contener {1} caracteres de largo.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I display the list of cities from my CitiesDetailsModal () method?

Do I have to change my method GetCountriesWithCities () ?? Or can I drive via Linq an IQueryable?

```
  public IQueryable GetCountriesWithCities()
  {
     return this.context.Countries.Include(c => c.Cities).OrderBy(c => c.Name);
  }
```

Any help for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you query for all countries, but want all the cities for the selected country instead?

Then filter and project those, materialize them into a list and send that to your view:

```
var allCities = paises.Where(c => c.Id == id.Value)
                      .SelectMany(c => c.Cities).ToList();
return View(allCities);
```

In order for this to work though, your `IQueryable`-returning method should be returning `IQueryable<Country>`.

Comment: No, I want only the cities of the countries to which I am hovering (those of the countryId) @CodeCaster

Comment: Yeah I've added the Where(). Why is id nullable?

Comment: When applying the "where" 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I now notice your method returns a non-generic `IQueryable`. Why? It should be `Iqueryable<Country>`.

Comment: Complement your answer with the section that you should specify that the method be IQueryable <Country> to accept your answer